# Proper way to use Twilio Add-ons for "Lookups" in Python

Tags: python, twilio

What is the proper way to us a Twilio Add-on that provides intelligence on a phone number for "Lookups" in Python?

Currently, I have it working with "Incoming Voice Call" and "Incoming SMS Message" (Note: you can see "lookups", "Incoming Voice Call: and "Incoming SMS Message" in the attached picture).

With "Incoming Voice Call" and "Incoming SMS Message", the information is automatically provided with the rest of the information pertaining to the call or SMS when Twilio makes it's initial request to my application. The problem with this is that in practice, I am paying 10 times over for many spam numbers that are constantly dialing in.

Instead, I would like to look up the information manually, only when I do not already have the information cached.

It looks like I can make a raw HTTPS request from Python to do this. Example:

```
https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+16505399600/?AddOns=nomorobo_spamscore&AddOns.nomorobo_spamscore.secondary_address=+15108675309
```

However, it seems like a more "proper" way would be to use the TwilioRestClient that comes with the [Twilio python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python). However, its not clear get this Add-on information through the Twilio python helper library. If I'm being honest, I have a lot of trouble understanding those docs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the [Twilio Python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) to achieve this with [Lookups](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) too. You can do a lookup, with the example URL you gave, like this:

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

number = client.lookups.phone_numbers("+16505399600").fetch(
  add_ons="nomorobo_spamscore",
  add_ons_data={
    "nomorobo_spamscore": {
      "secondary_address": "+15108675309"
    }
  }
)

print(number.add_ons)
```

`number.add_ons` will be a dict of the returned data from the Add-on. You pass the Add-ons you want to use with the `add_ons` argument (as a string or array of strings) and any further data in the `add_ons_data` argument.

Let me know if that helps at all.